# Forward slashes being stripped from Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL")

Tags: asp-classic, iis-8, request.servervariables

I'm having an issue with the following ASP Server Variable:

```vb
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL")
```

It is removing instances of multiple forward slashes, so the following URI:

```
/here/is//my/uri////as/an/example
```

Is interpreted as:

```
/here/is/my/uri/as/an/example
```

It's a fairly standard website setup on IIS 8.5.

Has anyone else come across a similar issue?

Comment: Is that a valid URI?

Comment: If I remember correctly, such duplicate slashes are removed by the browser when it sends out the requests. You should use the browser's developer tools or Fiddler to analyze further.

Comment: Tjanks @LexLi, I should have checked other websites before making this post, but your reply was very helpful.

Comment: if your issue is resolved I request you to post the helpful suggestion as an answer and mark it. it will help other people who face a similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Lex Li, the duplicate slashes are removed by the browser before sending the request to the server.